# Foreign Key Reference

Tags: sql, database-design, oracle11g, foreign-keys, rdbms

I addressed in class that the 2 foreign keys in the `FlightData` table are `Depart_Code` and `Ariv_Code` that there isn't any table to make references to them being a primary key in, in the relational schema we were given.

In class I was told that they reference `Airport_Code` in the `Airport` table. I was wondering I would go about doing that? I feel like I am missing something obvious. I appreciate any help offered I am still new to database in general and I am currently on Oracle 11g.

**Airport** table

```
CREATE TABLE Airport
(
     Airport_Code VARCHAR2(7) CONSTRAINT pk_Airport Primary Key,
     City_Code VARCHAR2(3), 
     CONSTRAINT fk_Airport_City_Code 
         FOREIGN KEY(City_Code) REFERENCES City, 
     Airport_Name VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

**FlightData** table:

```
CREATE TABLE FlightData
(
    Flt_Nbr VARCHAR2(3) CONSTRAINT pk_FlightData Primary Key,
    Depart_Code VARCHAR2(30), 
    Ariv_Code VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

Comment: If I understand correctly , Depart_code and Ariv_code are Airport codes , so they should be linked to the Airport table by FK , so those two columns are missing FK to Airport(Airport_Code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure `Depart_Code` and `Ariv_Code` always reference an airport in the `Airport` table you need to:

- Make these columns `NOT NULL`.
- Ensure they have the same data type as the key in `Airport`. Make them have a length of `7`.
- Add two foreign key constraints, each one based on each column.

For example, the second table could look like:

```
CREATE TABLE FlightData (
  Flt_Nbr VARCHAR2(3) CONSTRAINT pk_FlightData Primary Key,
  Depart_Code VARCHAR2(7) not null,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (Depart_Code) references Airport (Airport_Code),
  Ariv_Code VARCHAR2(7) not null,
  constraint fk2 foreign key (Ariv_Code) references Airport (Airport_Code)
);
```

Comment: Got it! Does that include making the Airport_Code NOT NULL also or just the departure and arrival code NOT NULL?

Comment: @user14658431 Airport_Code is the primary key of the Airport table. Primary keys are always NOT NULL, by definition.

Comment: I made the edits to the FlightData but I get: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (IT2309.FK2) violated - parent key not found                                                                                                      My code adjusted is  -- CREATE TABLE FlightData
(Flt_Nbr VARCHAR2(3) CONSTRAINT pk_FlightData Primary Key,
Depart_Code VARCHAR2(7) not null,
CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (Depart_Code) REFERENCES Airport (Airport_Code),
Ariv_Code VARCHAR2(7) not null,
CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY (Ariv_Code) REFERENCES Airport (Airport_Code)
);  @The Impaler

Comment: @user14658431 Your data is inconsistent. Remove all the data, create the foreign keys, and then insert the data again.